# Cqlsh does now work on newly installed Cassandra on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, cqlsh

I am getting this error when I try cqlsh or cqlsh 127.0.0.1:9160 :

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

I just started learning Cassandra. My machine had an installation of Cassandra for something else, so I uninstalled and installed Cassandra 3.11.1 to follow tutorials. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390775/how-can-i-reinstall-a-cassandra-on-ubuntu) to uninstall, I used [this](https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-install-apache-cassandra-on-ubuntu-16-04/) instruction to install.

My hosts file is:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
```

My python is version 2.7.12 and some Cassandra settings are:

```
start_rpc: false    
rpc_address: localhost
rpc_port: 9160
```

Cassandra status is active, and node was up and normal when I first tried "sudo nodetool status", but now it is erroting after I changed start_rpc to true and change it back to false :( Node error message is:

```
nodetool: Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused'.
```

I read [this](http://thelastpickle.com/blog/2016/08/16/cqlsh-broken-on-fresh-installs.html) and tried his suggestion, and it did not work.

Also, ideally, I want to use python 3. Is it a bad idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to connect to `native_transport_port`, the default value is 9042. I post this as answer as my user id permission can't post comment.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your input :) It was because of my improper uninstallation.

Answer (score 0):

My uninstalling did not properly delete Cassandra folders. Although I did tell its installer to make a new folders, it did not. I needed to purge Cassandra when I uninstall.