# cassandra reinstallation not working on ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, cassandra

It was wroking fine some days before all though i changed the size from **Xss:168k to 256k** and now I am facing this error while starting cassandra,although i have gone through existing solution but that are saying to compare existing file of **cassandra.yaml** and copy-paste the difference between them but not working for me, i am working on **ubntu-13.0.4** getting an error **ExceptionInInitializerError** ,**HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError**

```
 cassandra -f
 xss =  -ea -javaagent:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar -XX:+UseThreadPriorities -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -Xmn256M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError  -Xss256k
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Couldn't figure out log4j configuration: log4j-  server.properties
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.initLog4j(CassandraDaemon.java:103)
at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.<clinit>(CassandraDaemon.java:69)
```

any help and solution that work out,thanks.what changes do i have to make after reinstallation.

**Edit**

i have my log file in /etc/cassandra/log4j-tools.properties

```
# output messages into a rolling log file as well as stdout
log4j.rootLogger=WARN,stderr
# stderr
log4j.appender.stderr=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stderr.target=System.err
log4j.appender.stderr.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stderr.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p %d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %m%n
```

Comment: Change the value back and see if it fixes the problem, it really shouldn't since this is your error `Couldn't figure out log4j configuration: log4j-  server.properties`

Comment: nope again changing the value leads to stack size error.

Answer (score 0):

> Couldn't figure out log4j configuration: log4j- server.properties

This makes me thing that there is something wrong with your log4j config. The file is located in `/test/conf/log4j-server.properties`, or maybe its missing. [Check this question out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6574093/cassandra-starting-issue), I'd say its very closely related.

This is what the default looks like:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,R

# rolling log file ("system.log
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] %d{ISO8601} %F (line %L) %m%n
log4j.appender.R.File=build/test/logs/system.log
```

Comment: my file is present in /etc/cassandra log 4j tool properties,i didnt find any text/conf/log4j--server.properties

Comment: i have created and getting this:-xss =  -ea -javaagent:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar -XX:+UseThreadPriorities -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -Xmn256M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xss256k
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Couldn't figure out log4j configuration: log4j-server.properties
 at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.initLog4j(CassandraDaemon.java:103)
 at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.<clinit>(CassandraDaemon.java:69)

Comment: @user2801682 Could it possibly be a permissions issue?